# Error on An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, oledb, oledbconnection

can you please help me in VB.NET here is a picture of the  [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ElwU.jpg)..
 im getting crazy i can't find the error in the sentence

here goes the code

```
oConn.ConnectionString = strConn
oConn.Open()
If oConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
    ACommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT reparacoes.acessorios,maquinas.marca FROM reparacoes INNER JOIN maquinas on reparacoes.cod_maquina=maquinas.cod_maquina", oConn)
    'define um dataAdapter
    AAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
    AAdapter.SelectCommand = ACommand
    'define e preenche um DataTable com os dados
    ATabela = New DataTable()
    AAdapter.Fill(ATabela)
    ' associar campos a base de dados
    xy = ATabela.CreateDataReader
    ' Ler da tabela
    linha = ACommand.ExecuteReader
    While linha.Read()
    End While
End If
oConn.Close()
```

I can't find the error,

thanks for all your help
Best Regards
José Lopes

Comment: What is the purpose of creating a DataReader? Your data is already in the DataTable after the Fill and you can loop over the DataTable Rows. However, in the exception message there is an InnerException property that contains the exact reason for the error. Please [edit] your question adding this message

Comment: i use the data that come from linha.read
example linha("acessorios")

Comment: There is no need for it. _ForEach row as DataRow in ATabela.Rows_

Comment: Which line generates the error?

Comment: AAdapter.Fill(ATabela) sorry for not saying

Comment: The strange thing is that if its a normal sentence without the INNERJOIN it works, if i make like select * from reparacoes it works

Comment: I ask you again to tell us what is the Exception.InnerException.Message if any.

Comment: You don't need the `xy` line or the `linha` line as you've already filled the `DataTable` `ATabela`. Read what Steve has put. It will help you.

Comment: Have you tried creating the query in Access Query Builder? [Join tables and queries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6)

Comment: Andrew I dont even know what its that :) i always use the code like this, and in the past i never had problems, thats the strangest part, its that the problem must be in the sql sentence because if its a select etc it works just fine

Comment: Why do you refuse to post the inner exception as you have been requested several times?

Comment: It's this? sorry for being noob, heres a printscreen http://prnt.sc/e3o4rq

Comment: The error message says "Wrong type in expression." Are `reparacoes.cod_maquina` and `maquinas.cod_maquina` the same type in the database? You might get that error if, for example, one is a string and the other is a number.

Comment: Andrew Morton you are a GOD, the problem was that the cod_maquina in maquinas was in string, and it needed to be in number. OMG thank you so much <3